# DataPropertyName и DisplayMember, и рефакторинг

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

У ComboBox есть DisplayMember, а у DataGridView есть DataPropertyName.

Эти свойства используются при использовании DataSource, что бы забиндить данные.

А задаются эти 2 свойства строковыми константами, которые показывают название элемента коллекции, который нужно привязывать.

Вопрос, а можно ли эти свойства задавать как-нибудь иначе?

Я боюсь, что при использовании строковых констант, усложниться рефакторинг.

Например, в классе переименовали поле, которое биндилось. Во всем проекте переименовывание произошло, но студия проигнорировала привязки...

Answer (score 1):

В C#6 можно воспользоваться оператором [nameof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn986596.aspx).

Например:

```
class DataItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

И потом:

```
List<DataItem> data = new List<DataItem>(3);
data.Add(new DataItem() { ID = 1, Name = "Item 1" });
data.Add(new DataItem() { ID = 2, Name = "Item 2" });
data.Add(new DataItem() { ID = 3, Name = "Item 3" });

dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
Column1.DataPropertyName = nameof(DataItem.ID);
Column2.DataPropertyName = nameof(DataItem.Name);
```

Comment: А с коллекциями из анонимных типов, можно сделать что-то подобное?

Comment: @iluxa1810, честно говоря, не вижу способа. В данном случае имя свойства указывается через имя типа, у анонимных типов же имя генерируется только при компиляции.

Comment: Даже с помощью dynamic нельзя?

Comment: @iluxa1810, хм-м, не ожидал, но с dynamic сработало. Мне, однако, кажется, что это какое-то "неправильное" решение и возможно оно не лучше, чем задавать имя свойства строковой константой, т.к. nameof вычисляет имя на стадии компиляции. Если в коллекции могут быть объекты разных типов, то как вариант можно создать интерфейс, допустим `IDataItem`, который должны реализовывать все объекты, добавляемые в коллекцию, тогда коллекция будет `List<IDataItem>`, и, соответственно, имя свойства для привязки брать у интерфейса `nameof(IDataItem.ID)`.